# softmax dims and variable volatile in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have a code for previous version of PyTorch and I receive 2 warning for the 3nd line of it:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

def select_action(self, state):
        probabilities = F.softmax(self.model(Variable(state, volatile = True))*100) # T=100
        action = probs.multinomial(num_samples=1)
        return action.data[0,0]
```

> UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use `with
>   torch.no_grad():` instead.
>
> UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X > as an argument.

I found that:

> Volatile is recommended for purely inference mode, when you’re sure
>   you won’t be even calling .backward(). It’s more efficient than any
>   other autograd setting - it will use the absolute minimal amount of
>   memory to evaluate the model. volatile also determines that
>   requires_grad is False.

Am I right that I should just remove it?
And because I want to get probabilities therefore should I use dim=1 ?
and the 3nd line of my code should look like:

> ```
>     probabilities = F.softmax(self.model(Variable(state), dim=1)*100) # T=100
> ```

**state** is created here:

```
def update(self, reward, new_signal):
   new_state = torch.Tensor(new_signal).float().unsqueeze(0)
   self.memory.push((self.last_state, new_state, torch.LongTensor([int(self.last_action)]), torch.Tensor([self.last_reward])))
   action = self.select_action(new_state)
   if len(self.memory.memory) > 100:
       batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_action, batch_reward = self.memory.sample(100)
       self.learn(batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action)
   self.last_action = action
   self.last_state = new_state
   self.last_reward = reward
   self.reward_window.append(reward)
   if len(self.reward_window) > 1000:
       del self.reward_window[0]
   return action
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right but not "fully" right.

Except changes you mentioned you should use `torch.no_grad()` as mentioned like this:

```
def select_action(self, state):
    with torch.no_grad():
        probabilities = F.softmax(self.model(state), dim=1)*100
        action = probs.multinomial(num_samples=1)
        return action.data[0,0]
```

This block turns off autograd engine for code within it (so you save the memory similarly to `volatile`).

Also please notice `Variable` is deprecated as well (check [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated)) and `state` should be simply `torch.tensor` created with `requires_grad=True`.

BTW. You have `probs` and `probabilities` but I assume it's the same thing and merely a typo.

Comment: I have edited the initial post and included in it a piece of code in which the **state** is created. Do you meant that I should correct it to: **new_state = torch.Tensor(new_signal, requires_grad=True)** and remove **.float().unsqueeze(0)** ?

Comment: @Kosh `new_state = torch.Tensor(new_signal, requires_grad=True).float().unsqueeze(0)`. You shouldn't remove it as it's just casting tensor to specific type and adding additional first dimension (probably batch).

Comment: after adding **requires_grad=True** I start receiving TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, requires_grad=bool), but expected one of:
 * (*, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: requires_grad
 * (torch.Storage storage)
 * (Tensor other)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, torch.device device)
 * (object data, *, torch.device device)

Comment: @Kosh version of pytorch? And try `torch.tensor` instead as a quick fix

Comment: The same error for pytorch 1.0 and to 1.5. Sorry, I did not understand what you had meant here: **And try torch.tensor instead as a quick fix**

Comment: @Kosh [`torch.tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor) instead of `torch.Tensor`. Small instead of capital letter

Comment: `self.last_state = torch.tensor(input_size, requires_grad=True).unsqueeze(0)`
now returns
**RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point dtype can require gradient**
I tried adding `dtype=torch.float` to it but after that there was another error here:
`return map(lambda x: Variable(torch.cat(x, 0)), samples) #putting the samples in to pytorch variable`
**RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1**

Comment: @Kosh Those are different, you solved the first error correctly. In second case you shouldn't use `Variable` for the same reasons as previously, __it is deprecated__, so you are basically left with `torch.cat`. You have to step through this code and correct it manually if you wish for it to be warning-free and up to current standards (it definitely isn't ATM). Remember to check shapes and Google those errors and you should be just fine (or make a new question on StackOverflow if you are __seriously__ stuck).

Comment: Finally got it. The root of my problems was on the surface. You wrote that `probabilities = F.softmax(self.model(state), dim=1)*100` while it should be   `probabilities = F.softmax(self.model(state)*100, dim=1)` Actually I had understood a lot of stuff when I was troubleshooting this )

Answer (score 1):

I found same source code written in `python 2.7` - "Self Driving Car" application. I wasn't able to install `pytorch`/`pytorch-cpu` for `python 2.7` (CUDA driver issues...) so I had to fix the code to run in `python 3.*` .

Here is what I changed to make it work (includes changes suggested above by other people):
update `select_action` and `learn` functions of `Dqn` class like this:

```py
    def select_action(self, state):
        with torch.no_grad():
            probs = F.softmax(self.model(state) * 100, dim=1)  # T=100
            action = probs.multinomial(num_samples=1)
            return action.data[0, 0]

    def learn(self, batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action):
        outputs = self.model(batch_state).gather(1, batch_action.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
        next_outputs = self.model(batch_next_state).detach().max(1)[0]
        target = self.gamma * next_outputs + batch_reward
        td_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(outputs, target)
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        td_loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```